# In python pandas I am getting a keyerror

Tags: python, pandas

I only have a couple of line just the imports for pandas and the excel files. All i am trying to do is iterate though rows to compare a col with something. I havent gotten to that part because the iterration for the row just goves a key error.
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_excel('Warranty Detail.xlsx')

s = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')

for ind, row in df.iteritems():
    print(row['Warranty'])

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-8c18bb0a3ba9> in <module>
      1 for ind, row in df.iteritems():
----> 2     print(row['Warranty'])
      3 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    869         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    870         try:
--> 871             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    872 
    873             if not is_scalar(result):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4403         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4404         try:
-> 4405             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4406         except KeyError as e1:
   4407             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'Warranty'
```

Comment: You don't have a column name 'Warranty' after you do import. Sometimes whitespace is a problem.  `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`

Comment: Check `df.columns` and `df.head()` and you'll likely find the problem

Comment: I do though, here is the output for df.columns

Comment: I do have a column though. Here is the out put for df.columns

Comment: Index(['Warranty'..

Comment: This error happens for every column. I have tried typing and copy and pasting it.

Comment: You're using the incorrect `iter`. `iteritems` gives you each column separately so `row['Warranty']` is wrong. `row` is really a column and you are trying to find the row with the Index Warranty, which doesn't exist. You probably meant `.iterrows`

Comment: Cool appreciated it. That worked

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As an aside, `iterrows()` is slow, and rarely necessary.